# Google Map Changes not being rendered in browser

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my javaScript code.

```
(function() {
      window.onload = function() {

    // Creating a reference to the mapDiv
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');

    // Creating a latLng for the center of the map
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71);

    // Creating an object literal containing the properties 
    // we want to pass to the map  
    var options = {
      center: latlng,
      zoom: 2,   
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // Creating the map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, options);
  }
})();
```

When i add the disableDefaultUI: true to the options variable and test it on my Browsers(Opera,Firefox,Chrome Canary) it does not disable the UI. I am currently using Eclipse Indigo on My Mac OSX version 10.6.8. Is there a problem with my browsers cache or something? My code seems to be okay. I can't understand why it does not render on the browsers.

```
var options = { 
zoom: 3,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71),
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
 disableDefaultUI: true
};
```

Comment: I made a mistake in referencing the javascript file in my html document. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember exactly why the disableDefaultUI property didn't do anything on maps I've worked on recently. The way I got round it was to control each ui element directly.

```
var options = {
    // Required map properties here

    // Set how Zoom is to look
    zoomControl : true,
    zoomControlOptions : {
        style : google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    }
}
```

While the example above modifies the Zoom controls to the compact plus and minus rather than slider, you can turn if off using:

```
zoomControl : false
```

All the other UI elements have these type of controls also. [You can see them all here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls)

Comment: Thank you David i will check them out :)

Comment: David..Is there any content assist for google API.Typing them in eclipse is just so painful.

Comment: The only content assist you'll get in Eclipse is to have the full api imported into the project, other than that you may find content assist docs that just list the prototypes / functions online.

Comment: Importing the [Closure Externs](http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/externs/maps/) should help.

Comment: How should i go about importing it. I am using aptana studio 3 at the moment.